# MATLAB: copy zero-entries in array

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

I got a large vector `vec` of size `n x 1` (with `n` a huge number). All values in `vec` are `0` or `1`. The vector consists out of blocks of size `m` and in each block, only one of these two values shall be included.

So as to ensure this condition, I loop over each start element within an block and copy this value into all the entries of the respective block:

```
for i = 1:m:n
     if vec(i) == 1
          vec(i:i+m-1) = 1;
     else
          vec(i:i+m-1) = 0;
     end
end
```

How can I achieve this without loosing a loop so as to better use MATLABs vectorization parallelization? Thanks in advance

Comment: A little advice, when using `:` use parentheses to ensure the behaviour with respect to the iteration index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
vec = repelem(vec(1:m:n), m);
```